# Apache Virtual host site is very slow on https but fast on http

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, virtualhost

**Backgroud**: I have a multiple virtual host site setup on two webservers behind an ELB. Each virtual host site has an ssl certificate and key(domain.key,domain.bundle.crt) under /etc/httpd/ssl. There is also a Route53 setup which direct the traffic to my ELB and the to these webservers.

**Issue**: I have a site say site1.com and site2.com is setup as an alias in site1.com config file. So when I access http://site2.com(http) then its considerably fast compared to https://site2.com(https).

I have checked the site1.com virtual host logs but didnt find any error also I have checked the 01-cgi.conf file under /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d but didnt find any MaxRequestWorkers setting

```
# This configuration file loads a CGI module appropriate to the MPM
# which has been configured in 00-mpm.conf.  mod_cgid should be used
# with a threaded MPM; mod_cgi with the prefork MPM.

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
   LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
   LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
   LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
```

How could I resolve this issue.

Comment: Could someone let me know the solution or  workaround